# How to describer "Checking with alliances/signed-agreements to see if something is permitted/lawful" in two or three words

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, expressions, phrase-requests, vocabulary

If your boss asks you if we (that is, our company) can do something (like a particular import from a company in another particular country), and you say that we will have to check with the agreements you have signed with our partners.

How can you describer that in the form of noun - something like "Conditions Checking", or "Agreement Checking"?

What would be the correct/appropriate alternative to "Conditions checking", "Agreements Checking"?

What I want to describe in 2 or three words is: CHECKING the written/signed agreements/alliances to see if something is allowed.

---

EDIT: I am looking for a term for CHECKING the rules to see if we are working in compliance with them.

Comment: Please use this in a sentence. It is highly unclear whether you want a verb or a noun, or a phrase, or whether you in fact want a synonym. *Checking conditions* is a verb but *condition checking* is a noun. Note that the compound noun uses a singular not a plural, as in *baby food*.

Comment: We would NOT use just "Conditions checking" or "Agreements Checking", the shortest I would write it would be something like "checking our partner agreements".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is commonly used for company mergers and acquisitions, [Due Diligence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due%20diligence) can be applied to any business transaction.

> research and analysis of a company or organization done in preparation for a business transaction (as a corporate merger or purchase of securities)

More generally, you could use a word like *validation*, *verification* or *authentication*.